# Launch javascript onclick on slider revolution button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onclick, slider

I am trying to open a content locker script when a button layer is clicked  in slider revolution v5 but cannot figure it out.

Here is the code I have to launch the gateway

```
<a href="#" onclick="launch_gate();">Launch Gateway</a>
```

I have the script that will be launched inserted into a html/text layer and have tried using the action "simulate click" and "callback" to no avail.

Help please?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to set the ID (one of the atributes of all the layers) for your button.

After that using for example jQuery you can set your function to be launched as onClick action of your layer.

```
function hello(){
 alert("hello function");
}

jQuery("#your_button").click(hello);
```

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!